# Clicked button doesn't really function by Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I've been trying to click a button that downloads a CSV file from "https://mol.org/regions/?regiontype=countries". I'm sure that I've selected the button, as I can print the text written on it, but whenever I try to `.click()` it, it doesn't download the file. Are there any additional steps needed to operate the function bound to the button? Thank you in advance.

PS : The button works manually.

Here is the driver code I used :

```
with webdriver as driver:
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, search_bar_CSS_Selector))).send_keys(search_query+Keys.RETURN)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(download_button_CSS_Selector).click()
    print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(download_button_CSS_Selector).text)
    driver.close()
```

You can see that I actually print the button text & can access it, but the `.click()` is not working as expected.

Variables :

```
search_query = 'Egypt'
search_bar_CSS_Selector = "input[placeholder='Filter Political boundaries']"
download_button_CSS_Selector = "button[ng-click ='initiateDownload()']"
```

Comment: Does it work manually ?

Comment: @Muhammed Ezzat Can you just try this XPath ((//*[normalize-space()='Download full list'])[3]) for the download button

Comment: @YaDavMaNish Can't find that XPath unfortunately.

Comment: @MuhammadEzzat try with incognito mode

Comment: @YaDavMaNish : why would you suggest that xpath, when we already have a good css selector ? What's the need to perform this in incognito mode ?

Comment: @cruisepandey well there is no specific reason for that, maybe we should look at the other available options if the things are not working instead of spamming comments, To run in the incognito mode, well I saw the some cache issue while searching the name so suggested.

Comment: @YaDavMaNish : This is not a spamming, I wanna learn more and more everyday. so I asked if you had any specific reason for that

Comment: @cruisepandey same here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `css selector` looks perfect, but I think `it's a page loading issue`. So I tried that with an `explicit wait command` (check below) and it seems working fine.

**Sample code  :**

**so instead of this  :**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(download_button_CSS_Selector).click()
```

**use this :**

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[ng-click ='initiateDownload()']"))).click()
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver.get("https://mol.org/regions/?regiontype=countries")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Filter Political boundaries']"))).send_keys('Egypt'+Keys.RETURN)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[ng-click ='initiateDownload()']"))).click()
```

Comment: I tried using this line, still no downloaded file. If you successfully downloaded the file, could the problem come from another source? I'm really new to Selenium & still figuring things out. :D

Comment: Well I could download. What went wrong ? Can you remove driver.close and check again ?

Comment: I did so. There are no errors, it just finishes executing, prints the button text & nothing else.

Comment: Couldn't download too. I will try checking it on another machine.

Comment: Sorry for being late, I was on a vacation. Yes, it works indeed. I guess there is an issue that needs to be solved with my machine., perhaps the OS.